# How to map on a vec and use a closure with pattern matching in Rust

Tags: iterator, pattern-matching, closures, rust, filtering

I'd like to use `map` to iterate over an array and do stuff per item and get rid of the for loop. An error which I do not understand blocks my attempt. What I want to achieve is to iterate through a vector of `i32` and match on them to concat a string with string literals and then return it at the end.

Function:

```
pub fn convert_to_rainspeak(prime_factors: Vec<i32>) -> String {
    let mut speak = String::new();
    prime_factors.iter().map(|&factor| {
        match factor {
            3 => { speak.push_str("Pling"); },
            5 => { speak.push_str("Plang"); },
            7 => { speak.push_str("Plong"); },
            _ => {}
        }
    }).collect();
    speak
}

fn main() {}
```

Output:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:10:8
   |
10 |     }).collect();
   |        ^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `B`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Iterator::collect`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) is defined as:

```
fn collect<B>(self) -> B 
where
    B: FromIterator<Self::Item>
```

That is, it returns a type that is up to the caller. However, you have completely disregarded the output, so there's no way for it to infer a type. The code misuses `collect` when it basically wants to use `for`.

In your "fixed" version (which has since been edited, making this paragraph make no sense), you are being very inefficient by allocating a string in every iteration. Plus you don't need to specify any explicit types other than those on the function, and you should accept a `&[i32]` instead:

```
fn convert_to_rainspeak(prime_factors: &[i32]) -> String {
    prime_factors.iter()
        .map(|&factor| {
            match factor {
                3 => "Pling",
                5 => "Plang",
                7 => "Plong",
                _ => "",
            }
        })
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", convert_to_rainspeak(&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
}
```

Comment: _allocating strings_: should I use a constant &str and use its variable in the match?  
_what is &{T]_: Sorry I never saw this before - will look up the doc but mybe you have a good explanation as well

Comment: `&[T]` is [a *slice*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/primitive-types.html#slices); the official documentation does a good job of describing it. I'm unclear what you mean by the constant and using it in the `match`. A string literal is a constant and has no allocation. Your old (pre-edit) code mapped each element to a `String`, not a `&str`, and then collected to another `String`. I was referring to the inner `String` with the extra allocations.

Answer (score 1):

The error in this case is that the compiler can't figure out what type you are `collect`ing into. If you add a type annotation to `collect`, then it will work:

```
pub fn convert_to_rainspeak(prime_factors:Vec<i32>) -> String{
    let mut speak = String::new();
    prime_factors.iter().map(| &factor| {
        match factor {
            3 => {speak.push_str("Pling");},
            5 => {speak.push_str("Plang");},
            7 => {speak.push_str("Plong");},
            _ => {}
        }
    }).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    speak
}
```

However, this is really not the idiomatic way to do this. You should use `for` instead:

```
pub fn convert_to_rainspeak(prime_factors:Vec<i32>) -> String {
    let mut speak = String::new();
    for factor in prime_factors.iter() {
        match *factor {
            3 => speak.push_str("Pling"),
            5 => speak.push_str("Plang"),
            7 => speak.push_str("Plong"),
            _ => {}
        }
    }

    speak
}
```

Comment: Ah ok...Is there any case to use  iter().map() then?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `.map()`?

Comment: @xetra11: `map` is to be used when not immediately collecting the result into a collection, to avoid materializing an intermediate collection which is throw-away.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `flat_map()` instead of `map()`.
This way you can map to `Option` and return `None` instead of empty string if there is no corresponding value.

```
fn convert_to_rainspeak(prime_factors: &[i32]) -> String {
    prime_factors
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|&factor| match factor {
            3 => Some("Pling"),
            5 => Some("Plang"),
            7 => Some("Plong"),
            _ => None,
        })
        .collect()
}


fn main() {
    println!("{}", convert_to_rainspeak(&[1, 2, 3, 7]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

few minutes later I solved it myself (any upgrade appreciated):

```
pub fn convert_to_rainspeak(prime_factors:Vec<i32>) -> String{
    let mut speak:String = prime_factors.iter().map(|&factor| {
        match factor {
            3 => {"Pling"},
            5 => {"Plang"},
            7 => {"Plong"},
            _ => {""}
        }
    }).collect();
    speak
}
```

The issue was that I was not aware that `.collect()` is awaiting the result of map. I then assigned `prime_factors.iter()...` to a string and rearranged var bindings so it now all works.

EDIT: refactored redundant assignments to the speak vector